# Is it possible to force empty Reply-To header in mail?

Tags: python, outlook, smtplib

When I send mail with header like this `message['Reply-To'] = ''` (Python), it work fine on localhost. When I click **Reply** in Outlook at that received mail, **To** field is empty. When I send the same mail from production via company SMTP server, the mail also contains empty Reply-To header, however If I click **Reply** in Outlook, the address from that the mail had been received is prefilled in **To** field.

Is there a bug in company SMTP or why does it work only in localhost?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Reply-To empty, Outlook would default to the sender address. IMHO that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: But it works on localhost in Outlook as expected... :)

Comment: Are you usre there Sender MIME header?

Comment: Here you can see the difference between header of mail sent via company SMTP server (on the left) and via localhost (on the right). https://i.ibb.co/841Dc1t/smtp.png

Comment: I've tried to add Return-Path header on localhost but it doesn't affect Reply-To. :/